# NLTK Download SSL Certificate Failed

Tags: python, ssl, nltk

I tried to use nltk.download("stopwords") via nltk in Python, but it gave an SSL certificate error.

I was waiting for Stopwords to load and I came across the following error.

[nltk_data] Error loading stopwords: <urlopen error [SSL:

[nltk_data] CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed:

[nltk_data] unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)>